# Why did I randomly lose access to windows command promt?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, command-prompt, auto-py-to-exe

A bit of background:
I'm trying to convert a python tkinter script I have into an `.exe` for my coworkers to use. I installed `pyinstaller` successfully and was able to run `pyinstaller my_script.py --onefile` however I could never get my application to open due to a `windows cannot open` error. I thought this had to do with how pyinstaller ran so I kept deleting my app and associated files to try again. Eventually I tried using `auto-py-to-exe` to get this job done so I installed that. When I went to run this by simply entering `auto-py-to-exe` I got the `Access is Denied` error, and when I went back to trying `pyinstaller` again I started getting `Access is Denied` for that as well. Even if I just try to run `pyinstaller --help` I'll get `Access is Denied`. I don't understand how I could randomly get locked out like that and any help would be appreciated.

I've tried googling and troubleshooting this issue and I haven't really been able to find anything that seems to help me. This is a work machine that I'm using and I don't have access to the admin profile so I am unable to run any of these commands as an administrator.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting to make sure you don't have a running process that's holding a lock on some file you're trying to work with?  Failing that, check with your IT team to make sure they aren't blocking the tools you're trying to use.

Comment: @Samwise Yes I have rebooted, I've mentioned it to IT but they didn't provide any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into a permission issue on your work machine, which is preventing you from executing PyInstaller and auto-py-to-exe.

Unfortunately, since you don't have administrative rights on the machine, there might not be much you can do to resolve the issue. However, here are a few suggestions that you can try:

Check if there are any restrictions set by your IT department that are preventing you from executing the software.

Try to run the commands from a different command prompt or terminal, such as the Anaconda prompt.

If you have access to a different machine, you can try using that to compile the script instead.